# TypeError: Type uint256[4] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[] memory but they are all uint256?

Tags: solidity

I am trying to make a function more efficent, but getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Type uint256[4] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[] memory.
```

Here is my funciton:

```
function requestUnstake(uint _stakeIndexNo) public returns(bool, uint) {
    AllUserStakedTimestamp storage allUserStakedTimestamp = allUserStakes[msg.sender];
    uint[] memory prm = [
        allUserStakedTimestamp._epochDuration[_stakeIndexNo], // interval
        allUserStakedTimestamp._timeOfStake[_stakeIndexNo],   // time at stake
        allUserStakedTimestamp._timesOfRelease[_stakeIndexNo],// time release
        allUserStakedTimestamp._rewardPerCycle[_stakeIndexNo] // reward per cycle
    ];
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you "I cannot *implicitly* create this array for you".

The hint is that you need to declare it *explicitly*, like so (putting the length `4` in the initialization):

#### Basic Example for Syntax

```
uint[4] memory balance = [uint(1), 2, 3, 4];
```

#### Your Case

So you need this:

```
uint[4] memory prm = [
        allUserStakedTimestamp._epochDuration[_stakeIndexNo], // interval
        allUserStakedTimestamp._timeOfStake[_stakeIndexNo],   // time at stake
        allUserStakedTimestamp._timesOfRelease[_stakeIndexNo],// time release
        allUserStakedTimestamp._rewardPerCycle[_stakeIndexNo] // reward per cycle
    ];
```